# rsps where to find background image

Tags: java

I am  developing an rsps and cant seem to find where to find the background image
i found the loading screen but cant find the background image any ideas on what to search?

loading screen code

```
try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                if (!new File(signlink.findcachedir() + "load" + i + ".png").exists()) {
                    String url = "";
                    switch (i) {
                    case 1:
                        url = "http://Morytania.org/load1.png";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        url = "http://Morytania.org/load2.png";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        url = "http://Morytania.org/load3.png";
                        break;
                    }
                    HttpDownloadUtility.downloadFile(url, signlink.findcachedir());
                }
                loadingSprites[i - 1] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                        .getImage(signlink.findcachedir() + "load" + i + ".png");
            }
            super.graphics.drawImage(loadingSprites[0], 0, 0, null);
            super.graphics.drawImage(loadingSprites[1], 5, clientHeight - 35, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you're using revision 317 of the RuneScape client. In the older versions of the engine, such as the one you're using, the background is, by default, loaded from the game cache.

Inside of archive 0, there is a file labelled "title". Inside of that file, you may find the actual background ("title.dat") as the login box ("titlebox.dat") and buttons ("titlebutton.dat"). These files are simply JPEG images.

[image: archive 0]
[image: title file]

The background itself is stored as a 383x503 image that is then mirrored in-engine to create the full image. See [`createTitleBackground()`](https://github.com/thedaneeffect/RuneScape-317/blob/67c29aec892952d9b57ea6fd1387a37bd850c78d/src/main/java/Game.java#L3478). An excerpt of the code can be found below.

[image: title.dat]

```java
    public void createTitleBackground() throws IOException {
        Image24 image = new Image24(archiveTitle.read("title.dat"), this);
...
        // Flips the title background horizontally
        int[] tmp = new int[image.width];
        for (int y = 0; y < image.height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < image.width; x++) {
                tmp[x] = image.pixels[(image.width - x - 1) + (image.width * y)];
            }
            System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, image.pixels, image.width * y, image.width);
        }
...
    }
```

The code above is then called in the [`load()`](https://github.com/thedaneeffect/RuneScape-317/blob/67c29aec892952d9b57ea6fd1387a37bd850c78d/src/main/java/Game.java#L619) method:

```java
            archiveTitle = loadArchive(1, "title screen", "title", archiveChecksum[1], 25);
            fontPlain11 = new BitmapFont(archiveTitle, "p11_full", false);
            fontPlain12 = new BitmapFont(archiveTitle, "p12_full", false);
            fontBold12 = new BitmapFont(archiveTitle, "b12_full", false);
            fontQuill8 = new BitmapFont(archiveTitle, "q8_full", true);

            createTitleBackground();
            createTitleImages();
```